# Jackson Serialization with recursive structure only printing qNodeId and not additional child nodes

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have 3 main Node types as follows: Node, CNode, QNode. The QNode has can have a list of CNodes which can refer to other CNodes but never to the parent QNode. The QNode is a type of Node but with additional fields, so it extends from Node which is the most basic Node. I am having problems serialization this structure into JSON and to Java objects. There is also a TypeInfo class that can have an optional Node reference. TypeInfo is optional in QNode. When I serialize and print the result object I am only able to get the qNodeId of the QNode and its additional properties but not the child node objects. Here is my attempt. I would really appreciate very much any help with this issue as I have been on it for a while with no success

First the sample json input

```json
{
  "qNodes": [
    {

        "qNodeId": "Q-11122",
        "id": "PO11111",
        "typeInfo": {
          "applicationLevel": "medium",
          "required": true
         },
        "cNodes": [
          {
              "cNodeId": "Q-11155",
              "cNodes": [
                {
                  "qNodeId": "Q-7420",
                  "typeInfo": {
                    "applicationLevel": "low",
                    "assetNode": {
                      "id": "WQ-222",
                      "qNode": {
                        "qNodeId": "Q-0988"
                      }
                    },
                    "required": true
                  },
                  "url": "https://example.com ",
                  "id": "qS111"
                }
              ]
          }
        ]
      }
  ]
}
```

Next here is the Node class

```java
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    import lombok.Data;

    @Data 
    public class Node {
      public String id;
      public QNode qNode;

      @JsonCreator
      public Node(@JsonProperty("qNode") QNode qNode, 
   @JsonProperty("id") String id){
         this.id = id;
         this.qNode = qNode;
     }
   }
```

Here is the QNode class

```java
   import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
   import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
   import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
   import lombok.Data;

   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Map;

   @Data
   public class QNode extends BaseNode{
     @JsonProperty("qNodeId")
     private String qNodeId;
     @JsonProperty("cNodes")
     private List<CNode> cNodes;
     private TypeInfo typeInfo;
     private Map<String, String> additionalElements = new HashMap<>();


    @JsonCreator
    public QNode(@JsonProperty("qNode") String qNode,
                 @JsonProperty("id") String id
                 ) {
        super(id);
        this.qNode = qNode;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void additionalElements(String property, String value) {
        this.additionalElements.put(property, value);
    }
}
```

Here is the CNode class

```java
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public class CNode {
      private String cNodeId;
      private QNode qNode;
      @JsonCreator
      public CNode(@JsonProperty("cNodeId") String cNodeId,@JsonProperty("qNode")QNode 
      qnode){
        this.cNodeId = cNodeId;
        this.qNode = qnode;
    }
}
```

And finally the TypeInfo class

```java
    public class TypeInfo {
    public enum Level {
        low,
        medium,
        high;
    }
    private Level applicationLevel;
    private Node assetNode;
    private boolean required;
}
```

Here is BaseNode:

```java
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class BaseNode {
    protected String id;
    protected Map<String, String> additionalProperties = new 
    HashMap<>();

    @JsonCreator
    public BaseNode(@JsonProperty("id") String id) {
        this.id = id;

    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void additionAnswerProperties(String property, String 
  value) {
        additionalProperties.put(property, value);
    }

  }
```

Here is the container where the nodes are collected:

```java
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    import lombok.Data;

    import java.util.List;

    @Data
    public class QNodeContainer {
      List<QNode> qNodes;

      @JsonCreator
      public QNodeContainer(@JsonProperty("qNodes") List<QNode> 
 qNodes){
        this.qNodes = qNodes;
    }
 }
```

Here is how I read the json into the class:

```java
    File resource2 = new ClassPathResource(
                "data.json").getFile();
        String dataJson = new String(
                Files.readAllBytes(resource2.toPath()));
        ObjectMapper mapper = new 
 ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        QNodeContainer qNodes = mapper.readValue(dataJson, 
               QNodeContainer.class);
```

Comment: So you're facing the problem with Serialization, right? Firstly, do you've have all required **getters**? (I don't see them in the `Node`, `CNode` and `TypeInfo` classes, only has `QNode` has `@Data` annotation on it). Secondly, there's a bit of mess in the code: `BaseNode` imply `Node`? If yes, then why `qNode` property is not initialized (and there's no one-arg constructor declared) ?

Comment: I am using Lombok so I use the @NoArgConstructor which provides thee default constructor. I am reading using mapper.readValue(json, QNode.class)

Comment: What about **getters**? And about `BaseNode`? Please read [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73994266/jackson-serialization-with-recursive-structure-only-printing-qnodeid-and-not-add?noredirect=1#comment130650669_73994266) carefully and reflect clarifications in the question (use *edit* button or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73994266/edit) to update it). It's not a nitpick. To put it simple, we're not mind-readers, in order to provide helpful feedback the question should contain all the information relevant to the problem.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I completely missed adding the BaseNode code. Node is different from BaseNode. I hope adding the BaseNode class helps clarify the code.

Comment: Updated fully, you should be able to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to perform *deserialization* and subsequent *serialization* of the JSON you've provided after applying some changes.

The very first advice: before examining serialization of a complex object graph, have a look at smaller pieces. And when you're certain that all custom types can be *serialized/deserialized* as expected separately, it's time to check the whole thing.

These are the issues I found:

- `QNode` effectively has two methods annotated with `@JsonAnySetter`: `additionalElements()` and `additionAnswerProperties()` inherited from `BaseNode`. That's a huge No-No, this annotation is used to handle **all** the unmapped properties which can be found in the input JSON. There should at most **one** such annotation, either of these two maps and methods in `QNode` and `BaseNode` should be removed. If for some reason you need to separate some of these properties into another map, then they need to be grouped in the JSON-input under a particular well-defined name.
- You might want to use [`@JsonAnyGetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnyGetter.html) annotation to flatten the data contained in the map `additionalProperties` (I've applied it, pay attention to the comments to spot the changes).
- JSON representation of `CNode` is inconsistent with your POJO. There's a JSON-array, whilst the field in the class is type `QNode` (I've changed it to `List<QNode>`).
- Some getters were absent (see the comments).

That's the edited version:

```
@Data
public class Node {
    public String id;
    public QNode qNode;
    
    @JsonCreator
    public Node(@JsonProperty("qNode") QNode qNode,
                @JsonProperty("id") String id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.qNode = qNode;
    }
}

@Data
public class QNode extends BaseNode {
    @JsonProperty("qNodeId")
    private String qNodeId;
    @JsonProperty("cNodes")
    private List<CNode> cNodes;
    private TypeInfo typeInfo;
//        private Map<String, String> additionalElements = new HashMap<>(); // see the comment above `additionalElements()`
    
    
    @JsonCreator
    public QNode(@JsonProperty("qNode") String qNode,
                 @JsonProperty("id") String id
    ) {
        super(id);
        this.qNodeId = qNode; // changed from `this.qNode = qNode;` which raised a compilation error
    }

//        @JsonAnySetter // <- conflicts with @JsonAnySetter on `additionAnswerProperties()` inherited from the super class - there should be only one
//        public void additionalElements(String property, String value) {
//            this.additionalElements.put(property, value);
//        }
}


@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Getter   // <- added
@ToString // <- added
public class CNode {
    private String cNodeId;
    private List<QNode> qNodes; // <- QNode to List<QNodes>
    
    @JsonCreator
    public CNode(@JsonProperty("cNodeId") String cNodeId,
                 @JsonProperty("cNodes") List<QNode> qNodes) { // <- "qNode" to "cNodes" & QNode to List<QNodes>
        this.cNodeId = cNodeId;
        this.qNodes = qNodes;
    }
}

@ToString // <- added
@Getter   // <- added
public class TypeInfo {
    private Level applicationLevel;
    private Node assetNode;
    private boolean required;
    
    public enum Level {
        low,
        medium,
        high;
    }
}

@NoArgsConstructor
public class BaseNode {
    @Getter // <- added
    protected String id;
    @JsonAnyGetter // <- added
    protected Map<String, String> additionalProperties = new HashMap<>();
    
    @JsonCreator
    public BaseNode(@JsonProperty("id") String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    @JsonAnySetter
    public void additionAnswerProperties(String property, String value) {
        additionalProperties.put(property, value);
    }
}

@Data
public class QNodeContainer {
    private List<QNode> qNodes;
    
    @JsonCreator
    public QNodeContainer(@JsonProperty("qNodes") List<QNode> qNodes) {
        this.qNodes = qNodes;
    }
}
```

A code demonstrating *deserialization/serialization* of the JSON sample provided in the question:

```
String json = """
    past your JSON here
    """;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        
QNodeContainer qNodes = mapper.readValue(json, QNodeContainer.class);
        
System.out.println(qNodes);
        
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(qNodes));
```

Illustration of the **discrepancy** between the specified JSON representation and your Java-classes:

[image]

Comment: QNode have a list of CNodes which have cNodeId.  CNodes are identified by cNodeId

Comment: @BreenDeen "`QNode` have a list of `CNodes`"* - right, and `CNodes` in turn has a collection of `QNode` (but in your code it's a single object). Have a look at the highlighted JSON-array `"cNodes"` on the [**screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdp8a.jpg).

Comment: @BreenDeen There's a **discrepancy** between the specified JSON representation and your Java-classes. I would not be able to help you in resolving this **mismatch** without efforts from your side. I've added a demo-code which proves that the data now can be successfully deserialized and serialized.

Comment: Yes, I see it. I will modify the nodes and use your solution. Thanks a lot Alexander, I truly appreciate your help.